# Convert pygame app to kivy

Tags: python, pygame, kivy

I have written an application in pygame. It is a great framework but I want to have an easier process for bundling it for different platforms, including mobile. I have recently found [kivy](http://kivy.org). Here is my question:

What are the concrete steps I need to take to convert the pygame application to kivy?

**Update:** 
The reason I asked this question is it looks like kivy is built using pygame. I was wondering if there was a specific way to leverage that to ease conversion?

Comment: There is no 'one way' to do such a thing - you need to replace the code that uses PyGame features with equivalent code using Kivy's.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :( Any tips/links for easing this process?

Comment: Not really, it shouldn't be too hard to do, if the original code is well structured with suitable abstractions, but that's naturally a ship that has already sailed.

Comment: Thanks Lattyware. Maybe that's the route I'll take. I just hope bundling the application in kivy (for Windows, Mac, linux, etc.) isn't the pain it was with pygame/pyinstaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can't do that directly, as kivy, uses pygame as it's backend(when possible),
but the frontend is quite different, and it is not really much like pygame's so porting is quite different.

One way is to learn kivy, and port the app from Pygame => Kivy..

Comment: I guess I'll be learning kivy :) Thanks

Comment: If kivy is based on pygame, I wonder if kivy has a canvas object where you could access pygame directly. This way you could have the best of both worlds: blit for game graphics and UI widgets for menu and other UI from kivy